# input shape of dataset in CNN

Tags: deep-learning, python, keras

My dataset is a simple table of 20 columns and 100,000 rows.It is not a image data as commonly used in CNN. What input shape should I provide in this case?

Right now I did-

```
input_shape = (21,109713,1)

model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
```

which gives the error-

```
ValueError: rng_mrg cpu-implementation does not support more than (2**31 -1) samples
```

Comment: This question is for data science.se, the Only thing I can tell you is you are using keras which runs on tensorflow (an unpolished gem), since it is unpolished you many times need job specific codes... Anyways tensorflow was meant to be run on gpu, but you apparently lack it in your PC so it is running it on cpu which places many constraints on the type (since optimal parallelizable code on cpu has not been completely written by developers) and data on which you want to perform operations on...So the best way would be to divide your dataset into batches.

Comment: @DuttaA I dont think the size of the dataset is a problem...its only 100,000 and not a image dataset also..it just has 20 features and 100,000 rws

Comment: I dunno but somehow it is exceeding that...do not forget you are using 32 filters.

Comment: @DuttaA after running it again I am getting the error ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (109713, 19)

Comment: cov_2d takes a batch of data and not a single data sample

Comment: @DuttaA yes my dataset is a matrix of 20 columns whch are the features and 100,00 rows

Comment: CNN's take data in the form of NHWC, N-number of data samples, H-height of image, W - Width of image, C- number of channels...you have to somehow convert your non-image data to this form

Answer (score 2):

I have mentioned this in other posts also:

One can use `Conv1d` of `Keras` for usual features table data of shape `(nrows, ncols)`. To input features, following 2 steps are needed:

```
xtrain.reshape(nrows, ncols, 1)
# For conv1d statement: 
input_shape = (ncols, 1)
```

For example, taking first 4 features of iris dataset:

To see usual format and its shape:

```
iris_array = np.array(irisdf.iloc[:,:4].values)
print(iris_array[:5])
print(iris_array.shape)
```

The output shows usual format and its shape:

```
[[5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2]
 [4.9 3.  1.4 0.2]
 [4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2]
 [4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2]
 [5.  3.6 1.4 0.2]]

(150, 4)
```

Following code alters the format:

```
nrows, ncols = iris_array.shape
iris_array = iris_array.reshape(nrows, ncols, 1)
print(iris_array[:5])
print(iris_array.shape)
```

Output of above code data format and its shape:

```
[[[5.1]
  [3.5]
  [1.4]
  [0.2]]

 [[4.9]
  [3. ]
  [1.4]
  [0.2]]

 [[4.7]
  [3.2]
  [1.3]
  [0.2]]

 [[4.6]
  [3.1]
  [1.5]
  [0.2]]

 [[5. ]
  [3.6]
  [1.4]
  [0.2]]]

(150, 4, 1)
```

This works well for Conv1d of Keras. For input_shape (4,1) is needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Conv1D in keras. With Keras Conv1D you will not require 3D shape.

```
keras.layers.Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, strides=1, 
  padding='valid', data_format='channels_last', 
  dilation_rate=1, activation=None, use_bias=True, 
  kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', 
  bias_initializer='zeros', kernel_regularizer=None, 
  bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None,  
  kernel_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None)
```